# Expand/collapse list items in recursive tree menu in angular

Tags: json, angular, typescript, recursion

How can i achieve that my nested lists expand on click?
At the moment it just opens the first level.

**sidebar.component.html**

```
   <ul>
    <ng-template #recursiveList let-list>
      <li *ngFor="let item of list" (click)="listClick($event, item)">
        {{item.name}}
        <ul *ngIf="item.folders?.length > 0" [ngClass]="{ 'subfolder': selectedItem == item }">
          <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveList; context:{ $implicit: item.folders }"></ng-container>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveList; context:{ $implicit: list }"></ng-container>
  </ul>
```

Click from **sidebar.component.ts**

```
listClick(event, newValue) {
    console.log(newValue);
    this.selectedItem = newValue;
  }
```

The first level works like it should. I click on the folder name and it expands. But when I click on the list element on the next level the list collapses instead of expanding further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the event is bubbling up to the parent i.e. when you click on a child, you are also clicking on the parent element too. Adding `event.stopPropagation()` should stop the event bubbling to the parent. I.e.

```
listClick(event, newValue) {
    console.log(newValue);
    this.selectedItem = newValue;

    event.stopPropagation();
}
```

**Update**: I am not sure how your data is being fetched, so I am not sure if this is 100% right. But here is a working example of how it should work (you do need the `event.stopPropagation();`) I have added `&& item.showSubfolders` the `*ngIf` which gets toggled on click:

```
<ul>
    <ng-template #recursiveList let-list>
      <li *ngFor="let item of list" (click)="listClick($event, item)">
        {{item.name}}
        <ul *ngIf="item.folders?.length > 0 && item.showSubfolders" [ngClass]="{ 'subfolder': selectedItem == item }">
          <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveList; context:{ $implicit: item.folders }"></ng-container>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveList; context:{ $implicit: list }"></ng-container>
  </ul>
```

And the Listclick:

```
listClick(event, newValue) {
    console.log(newValue);
    this.selectedItem = newValue;
    newValue.showSubfolders = !newValue.showSubfolders
    event.stopPropagation()
  }
```

working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-emz37r

Comment: Thanks for your hint, but I already tried it. This only moves my problem to the next level. A click on the child element doesn't have any effect on the next level if I stopPropagation.

Comment: In the other case (without stopPropagation) my subelement gets an active status but parent gets inactive. That's what i want to prevent.

Comment: That's it! Thank you! :)